# Solr Fetching documents based from publication start and end dates

Tags: solr

How can I query all published documents based from its publication date range. I have the following datetime fields available on my index.

```
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" termOffsets="true" stored="true" termPositions="true" termVectors="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="publishStart" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="publishEnd" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

I want to achieve something like this SQL query conditional statement:

```
(publishStart <= now() AND publishStart is not null) AND (publishEnd >= now() OR publishEnd is null)
```

e.g.

Query should match the following documents:

let now() = 2016-06-14T08:00:00Z

```
      title:        Article 1
      publishStart: 2016-06-14T07:00:00Z

      title:        Article 2
      publishStart: 2016-06-14T07:00:00Z
      publishEnd:   2016-06-15T07:00:00Z
```

:) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you're looking for is

```
publishStart:[* TO NOW]  AND (-publishEnd:[* TO NOW] AND publishEnd:[* TO *])
```

Please notice that Solr doesn't have an easy way to specify that you need empty values,  so in the second part of the query,  we get all the results and exclude what we don't need. [Here](http://aaronbonner.io/post/25428518232/date-range-with-null-search-in-solr-4x) is an interesting article on the matter.